# Update a datagridview trick for checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a windows form which has a gridview. I want to update it by the [trick](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=132).
The code is:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Orders"];

       this.dgv.BindingContext[dt].EndCurrentEdit();

        this.da.Update(dt);

    }
```

It looks good. My question is that there is cell, which is a flag(defaulted to 0). Can we customize it as a checkbox?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn for that column. And do "manual" population by looping through rows of dgv, and if value is 1:

```
dgv[x,y].Value = true;
```

or 0 do nothing.

Comment: Do you mean clicking "Edit Column" then do something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170268/how-to-update-the-datagridview-when-editing-is-made can you help me sir